# Threaded network listener with return values

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I'm currently trying to accomplish a project, which listens multiple ports and recieves incoming data.

**DeviceListener class:**

-I have a method called **PortListener**. It take two parameters whic are IP and Port addresses. It continously listens a specific port for incoming data.

-The other method is called **StartListen** which runs the **PortListener** in a thread.

**Main program:**

-It gets the port list and starts **PortListener** for each port using **StartListen** method.

```
Psuedo Like Code:

class DeviceListener()
{

   private string PortListener(string ip, int port)
   {
      //listen ip and port. 
      //wait for data. 
      //recieve and return data.

      RecieveData();
      string data = recieved data;
      return data;
   }
   public void StartListen(string ip, int port)
   {
      //start PortListener in a thread
      Thread t = new Thread (() => PortListener(ip,port));
      t.Start();
   }

}

void Main()
{
   ip = ip adress;
   List portlist;
   foreach (port in portlist)
   {
      string data = DeviceListener.StartListen(ip, port);
   }
}
```

My problem is I just can't return the recieved data to my Main program.

Is there a way to get recieved datas for each PortListener thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a **delegate** method.

```
class DeviceListener()
{
    public delegate void PassData(string str);
    public PassData passdata;       

   private void PortListener(string ip, int port)
   {
      //listen ip and port. 
      //wait for data. 
      //recieve and return data.

      RecieveData();
      string data = recieved data;

      passdata(data);
   }
   public void StartListen(string ip, int port)
   {
      //start PortListener in a thread
      Thread t = new Thread (() => PortListener(ip,port));
      t.Start();
   }

}

void Main()
{
   DeviceListener.passdata = new DeviceListener.PassData(Some_Function);

   ip = ip adress;
   List portlist;
   foreach (port in portlist)
   {
      DeviceListener.StartListen(ip, port);
   }

   private void Some_Function(string data)
   {
      //do something with returned string.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following -

1. Add a queue of the data type you wish to receive. Best use the synchronized versions or create your own, depends on the .Net. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Add each new stuff you get into the queue and make the queue public so other classes could access it. Other threads that wish to access incoming data can read can read from the queue and block if the queue is empty or poll by periodically checking if there are items present.
2. Another option is to use events ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Your class can expose an event with the relevant data present and invoke it upon data arrival. Other classes will register and will get notified of new incoming data.

The first option is better if you have a single reading entity, the second is better if multiple entities are interested in the data.

Comment: Thank you Vadim. I'm gonna look to the articles.

Comment: This is exactly he right way, from a threading standpoint, to manage incoming data. Depending on the number of connections you expect, option 2 is probably better. Store the data, signal a thread that you have data available, then return. This allows you very low latency on servicing other connections. The thread can the process leisurely.